# Of what type is the result of a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, objectquery

Examples on LINQ gives this

```
var query = context.Contacts
    .Where(q => q.FirstName == "Tom");
```

I'm wondering what object is "query"? And also is it possible (advisable) to pass it to a method (within the same class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `query` object is most likely of type `IQueryable<Contact>`. You can of course pass it to a method, whether that is in the same class or in another class does not matter.

But keep in mind that LINQ does use a mechanism named "deferred execution". That means that query does not get enumerated immediately, but rather when it is needed. All the stuff you put in your query (the `Where`-clause for example) gets executed then. For more information about deferred execution have a look at [MSDN: Query Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx).

NB: You can find out the exact type of the `query` variable if you hover you mouse over it or the `var` keyword in Visual Studio.